# django ограничение в моделях

Tags: python, django

Есть вот такие модели:

```
class Catrige(Product):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model,models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Модель")
    original = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Оригинал")

class Printer(Product):
    firm = models.ForeignKey(Firm, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Производитель")
    printerModel = models.ForeignKey(PrinterModel, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Модель принтера")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Имя принтера")
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="ip-адрес")
    status = models.ForeignKey(PrinterStatus, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Статус принтера")
    catriges = models.ManyToManyField(Catrige,verbose_name="Установленый картридж", blank=True)
```

Каким образом можно ограничить добавление картриджа если он уже используется?
Именно на уровне модели что бы нельзя было не в админпанели добавлять уже используемые модели и на формах.

Comment: уникализировать параметры, по котрым принтер не может повторяться в бд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

зачем у принтеров и картриджей отношение многие ко многим? У вас же не может один картридж стоять в двух разных принтерах, сделайте просто внешний ключ, который не позволит разным принтерам иметь один и тот-же картридж.

Вам не нужны будут дополнительные ограничения, у каждого картриджа может быть только одно устройство, если модели будут примерно такими.

```
class Catrige(Product): 

    model = models.ForeignKey(Model,models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Модель") 
    original = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Оригинал")

    # тут делаем связь многие картриджи к одному устройству
    printer = models.ForeignKey(Printer, related_name='catriges', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Printer(Product): 
    firm = models.ForeignKey(Firm, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Производитель") 
    printerModel = models.ForeignKey(PrinterModel, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Модель принтера") 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Имя принтера") 
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="ip-адрес") 
    status = models.ForeignKey(PrinterStatus, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Статус принтера") 

    # тут связь нам не нужна, доступ к картриджам будет через related_name - cartriges
    # catrige = models.ForeignKey(Catrige, related_name='printer', verbose_name="Установленый картридж", blank=True)




Printer.objects.first().catriges.all()
<QuerySet [Catrige1, Catrige2]>
```